# perl regex remove specific lines

Tags: regex, perl

I have data files that are CSVish

Some entries don't have any commas, as they are subtitle headings.  I'd like to remove those lines.

Example data below (excuse generic data)
I'd like a regex/perl one liner to delete all the subtitle lines.  Thank you in advance

```
Title1  Books,
subtitleA
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
subtitleB
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
Title2  Posters,
subtitleC
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
subtitleD
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the below regex to match all the lines which has no commas .

```
^[^,\n]+$
```

or

```
^[^,\n]*$
```

After you could delete the matched lines.

Perl one-liner.

```
$ perl -ne 'print unless /^[^,]+$/' file
$ perl -ne 'print unless /^[^,\n]+$/' file
Title1  Books,
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
Title2  Posters,
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
items,1,2,3,4
days,1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `-i` for in place edit,

```
perl -i -ne 'print if /,/' file
```